# Как установить PySide, выдает ошибку

Tags: python, macos, pip, pyside

```
$ pip install PySide
Collecting PySide
  Using cached PySide-1.2.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    only these python versions are supported: [(2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4)]

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/d2/7068nyh14wz9f6dx6y327tww0000gn/T/pip-build-0sc324fn/PySide/
```

Приложите пожалуйста последовательность команд, как это можно установить, ибо pyenv с разными версиями питона и пипа пробовал вроде как. macOS Sierra

Comment: Какая у вас версия питона?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Python PyQt on macOS Sierra](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39821177/4279)

Comment: @AndrioSkur глобально 3.5.1, локально в директории 3.4.3 через pyenv